Rails 7, Dokku, and Whenever gem: How to create CRON jobs on production?
I followed a tutorial of setting up the whenever gem to schedule repetitive jobs. I created a rake task that I want to run and I configured the schedule.rb file:
set :output, 'log/whenever.log'
every 1.day, at: '1:00 pm' do
  runner "my_namespace:my_task"
end

I do deploy the code to my server with git push my-dokku-rails-app main. What I do know is where and how to execute the whenever --update-crontab --set environment='production' command.
If I SSH to my server, go to my dokku directory (/home/dokku/my-dokku-rails-app main) and run whenever --update-crontab --set environment='production', I get
Command 'whenever' not found, but can be installed with:
apt install ruby-whenever

EDIT: When I run bundle exec whenever --update-crontab --set environment='production', I get:
Command 'bundle' not found, but can be installed with:
snap install ruby          # version 3.3.1, or
apt  install ruby-bundler  # version 2.3.5-2
See 'snap info ruby' for additional versions.

EDIT2 I added the whenever command to the Dockerfile. The app is deployed to the server without any error, but when I run crontab -l to verify the CRON jobs were created, then there are none - crontab is empty.
# syntax = docker/dockerfile:1

ARG RUBY_VERSION=3.2.2
FROM registry.docker.com/library/ruby:$RUBY_VERSION-slim as base

WORKDIR /rails

ENV RAILS_ENV="production" \
    BUNDLE_DEPLOYMENT="1" \
    BUNDLE_PATH="/usr/local/bundle" \
    BUNDLE_WITHOUT="development" 

FROM base as build

RUN apt-get update -qq && \
    apt-get install --no-install-recommends -y build-essential curl git libvips node-gyp pkg-config python-is-python3 libpq-dev cron

COPY Gemfile Gemfile.lock ./
RUN bundle install && \
    rm -rf ~/.bundle/ "${BUNDLE_PATH}"/ruby/*/cache "${BUNDLE_PATH}"/ruby/*/bundler/gems/*/.git && \
    bundle exec bootsnap precompile --gemfile

    
COPY . .

# Create empty crontab file
RUN crontab -l | { cat; echo ""; } | crontab -

# Update crontab file using whenever command
RUN bundle exec whenever --update-crontab

RUN bundle exec bootsnap precompile app/ lib/

RAILS_MASTER_KEY
RUN SECRET_KEY_BASE_DUMMY=1 ./bin/rails assets:precompile

FROM base

RUN apt-get update -qq && \
    apt-get install --no-install-recommends -y curl libvips postgresql-client && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists /var/cache/apt/archives

COPY --from=build /usr/local/bundle /usr/local/bundle
COPY --from=build /rails /rails

RUN useradd rails --create-home --shell /bin/bash && \
    chown -R rails:rails db log storage tmp
USER rails:rails

ENTRYPOINT ["/rails/bin/docker-entrypoint"]

EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["./bin/rails", "server"]

How to configure whenever gem with dokku?

did you add require 'whenever/capistrano' to Capfile? add before, what do you use for deploy?

Did you try bundle exec whenever instead of just whenever?

@AntonBogdanov I don't use Capistrano.

@mechnicov added the output to the OP. I am wondering whether I should not be running that whenever command somehow manually through dokku on the server, OR to hardcode it to the Dockerfile that comes with Rails 7.1?

@user984621 have you tried just adding it to the Dockerfile? e.g. RUN bundle exec whenever --update-crontab?

@engineersmnky I had to add it to Dockerfile. The command you attached was throwing an error, so I had to add a variation of it to Dockerfile. It gets deployed to the server now, but it unfortunately still doesn't create the CRON job in crontab
